# Fragment options menu with ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager

I am using the `ActionBarSherlock` library inside of which a `ViewPager` is being implemented

So in my `ViewPager` class I have the following code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_slider, menu);
    return true;
}
```

And now in my Fragment class I have the following code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_menu, menu);
}
```

This code with the current implementation of the `ActionBarSherlock` does not work as opposed to it working when it does not use the library. How do I apply the fragment options menu with the library implementation ? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `fragment.setHasOptionsMenu(true)` when you return the new fragment in the ViewPager's adapter. That works for me.

Comment: isn't `setHasOptionsMenu()` a method ? could you please be more clear on this ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, setHasOptionsMenu(true) when you return your fragment in your ViewPager's adapter. If it's a FragmentPagerAdapter the fragment is returned in the getItem() method.